# Visio 2010 64-bit works for Tridion 2011

Tags: workflow

We are using Tridion 2011. Per documentation, the Workflow Designer client application requires one of the following
products:

- Microsoft Visio 2007 SP2, English version
- Microsoft Visio 2010 (32-bit), English version

Does anybody know whether it works with Visio 2010 64-bit?

Comment: Please can you add some details of what is not working, and how you know that?

Comment: @charles, Do you mean it is not working for 64 bit?  Your comment says 32-bit.  Please mark John's answer as "correct" and play the game of upvoting.

Comment: Thanks, Nickoli. I have deleted the old comment. Again, for everyone's information, it is NOT working with 64-bit Visio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at the installation documentation for both 2011 and 2013 and both highlight:

> Microsoft Visio 2010 SP1 (32-bit), English version

As the supported version to use, there's no mention of support for 64 bit.  I'd recommend contacting SDL support to clarify the situation as this may be a case of out-dated documentation.

Comment: It might just work if you try it.

Comment: The answer you'll get from support is that if it's not listed then we don't know if it works. If we tested it, we list it. I guess we didn't test 64 bit Visio (or we did and it didn't work), so you're on your own here.

Comment: I have verified that it is not working with 32-bit Visio, so you don't have to try again.

If working properly, you can see a new "Add In" tab which is from SDL. It is not showing up in 64-bit no matter how hard you try.